# Git - error: Unable to append to .git/logs/refs/heads/bugfix_artfXX

Tags: git, commit

I have created a branch to work on a bug fix and when done with my changes tried to commit but got following error:

```
git commit -a -m "."
error: Unable to append to .git/logs/refs/heads/bugfix_artfXX
fatal: cannot update HEAD ref
```

I read posts in [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and other websites pointing to the same problem and they mostly are fixed by fixing permissions. I tried to change to full permission on .git directory and all sub-directories but did not help.

What's strange to me is that I was able to commit until yesterday but today I get this annoying message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have lost your HEAD. Try the following:

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

See if this could solve your problem [Git fatal error](http://www.wentsch.me/git-fatal-error-couldnt-set-refsheadsmaster-cannot-update-head-ref)

Comment: Thanks @coffeMug. This actually solved my problem though I have no idea why I lost my HEAD. Thanks anyway!